# What are the numbers for in these LDAP commands ? ldap(3), slapd(8), slapd.conf(5), slurpd(8)

Tags: ldap, openldap, slapd

What do the numbers between parentheses stand for in the above commands, found within the LDAP galaxy?

I really cannot find anything out there, neither on the documentation, nor could I find any rationale for such an odd numbering style!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

These are very likely `man` sections:

```
   1   Executable programs or shell commands
   2   System calls (functions provided by the kernel)
   3   Library calls (functions within program libraries)
   4   Special files (usually found in /dev)
   5   File formats and conventions eg /etc/passwd
   6   Games
   7   Miscellaneous  (including  macro  packages  and  conventions), e.g.
       man(7), groff(7)
   8   System administration commands (usually only for root)
   9   Kernel routines [Non standard]
```

Comment: .. and one rationale for *mentioning the sections* is: distinct manuals of otherwise identical name might exist in multiple sections, e.g. calling `man 1 postconf` will bring up the manual for the *program* while `man 5 postconf` will bring up the manual for the *configuration file format*.